# Itemize environment inside definition environment does not give expected result

Tags: itemize

The following code produces output where the first `item' is appended to the line starting Definition, despite the line break. I would like to have the itemized list start below the definition.

```
\documentclass[reqno]{amsbook}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition:}[chapter]

\begin{document}

\begin{definition} 

\begin{itemize}
\item[(i)] Blah. \\
\item[(ii)] Blah blah.
\end{itemize}
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `itemize` environment will always start on a new line; here no line is skipped because it is already at the "beginning" of the line on which the definition starts. If you add something (for example a non-breaking space, as in the example below) on this line before the `itemize` environment, a line break will automatically be added.

[image]

```
\documentclass[reqno]{amsbook}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition:}[chapter]

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}~
\begin{itemize}
\item[(i)] Blah.
\item[(ii)] Blah blah.
\end{itemize}
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

Also, two unrelated comments:

- There is no need to manually add a line break at the end of an item, the `\item` command ensures that each new item starts on a new line.
- `amsfonts` is loaded by `amssymb`, so if you load `amssymb`, there is no need to load `amsfonts` separately.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on loading components.  Also, more importantly, for the answer.